# Find change in Col A and insert 4 rows using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, insert, vba

I'm trying to get my code to insert four rows every time it finds a difference in the cell below. If A5-55 = 1, A56-80 = 2, A81 - 100 = 3 I want the code to see that 56 isn't equal to 55 and insert 4 rows, then continue down the A column until there are no more values.

I keep getting an error from Excel,

> can not complete task. Resources error

And then a runtime 1004 insert method of range class failed, and the debugger highlights the code for inserting rows

[image]

[image]

This is what my data looks like:

[image]

```
Worksheets("HR-Calc").Activate
For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 6 Step -1

If Cells(lRow, "A") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "A") Then
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
End If
Next lRow
```

Comment: Running out of resources is bad XD How many rows do you have?

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping through the code via debug?  I wonder if somehow your code is causing an endless loop.

Comment: You should used Cells(lRow,1).Value or Range("A" & lRow).value. Cells takes row and column number (1,1) inputs and Range takes Cell Reference A1 type input

Comment: Also, to build on @findwindow 's questions, depending on how you have lRow declared you could be running out of space there. Integer data types only allow numbers between -32768 and 32767. So if you have more than 32767 rows, you should declare it as Long

Comment: i found the problem. I had a cell range that I copied, its used to find the last cell in a column and starts at a100000 then uses xlup to find the last row with data. I forgot to change that 100,000 and it pasted roughly 2 million cells of data at once hence the error. But Thanks for the notes and is there a better way to do this insert? it still looks clunky to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neater way would be to use an autofilter on the table

(The code assumes that column A is a sorted integer ID - as seems to be the case from the image)

```
Sub InsertRowsBetweenIncrements()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("HR-Calc")
    Dim HeaderRow As Long: HeaderRow = 4

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Columns(1).Find("*", _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Dim LastCol As Long: LastCol = ws.Cells.Find("*", _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        Dim Tbl As Range: Set Tbl = ws.Range(Cells(HeaderRow, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
        Dim i As Long, j As Long

        For i = ws.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value To 1 Step -1
            Tbl.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=i
            j = Tbl.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
            Tbl.AutoFilter
            If j <> HeaderRow And j < LastRow Then _
                ws.Rows(j + 1 & ":" & j + 4).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Col A is a count for location ID. the ID will restart every so often. block1 box1, block1 box2, block1 box3, block2 box 1 block 2 box2, block3 box1 etc etc. I insert 4 rows with every change that way I didn't need to run this macro twice once for the block #, and again for the box #.

Comment: Yes - that is what is assumed... It filters by each block# then inserts 4 rows below the last row (which will be a transition to the next block#)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a less-clunky was (as you mentioned), I would default to using arrays to increase speed. Give the code below a try and see what you think. This assumes your data starts in row 6 (if not, change the value of "offset" to the final row before the data in question starts). If you want to change how many rows you insert in the future, just change the value of rows_to_insert to the desired number.

```
Sub insertrows()

Dim check_col() As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim lcell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim rows_to_insert As Long
Dim rows_added As Long
Dim offset As Long
Dim insert_cell As Long

Worksheets("HR-Calc").Activate
lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set lcell = Cells(lrow, 1)
Set rng = Range("A6", lcell)
check_col = rng
rows_to_insert = 4
rows_added = 0
offset = 5

rows_added = 0
For i = 1 To (UBound(check_col, 1) - 1)
    If check_col(i, 1) <> check_col(i + 1, 1) Then
        check_col(i, 1) = i + rows_added + offset
        rows_added = rows_added + rows_to_insert
    Else: check_col(i, 1) = VBnllstring
    End If
Next i
check_col(UBound(check_col, 1), 1) = vbNullString
rows_to_insert = rows_to_insert - 1
For i = 1 To UBound(check_col, 1)
    If check_col(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then
        insert_cell = check_col(i, 1) + 1
        Range(Cells(insert_cell, 1), Cells(insert_cell + rows_to_insert, 1)).EntireRow.Select
        Range(Cells(insert_cell, 1), Cells(insert_cell + rows_to_insert, 1)).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```